# Writing an xsl when clause with multiple conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm fairly new to xslt so I may be missing something easy, but I can't seem to find it. I'm trying to construct a when clause with multiple condition. Herese what I have.

```
<xsl:when test="(string-length(current()/SSN/text())) = 9 AND not(string(number(current()/SSN/text())) = 'NaN')">
    <IdCodeQualifier>
        <xsl:value-of select="'34'" />
    </IdCodeQualifier>
    <SSN>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()/SSN/text()" />                  
    </SSN>
</xsl:when>
```

This results in:

> XSLT compile error at (97,16). See InnerException for details. 'boolean((string-length(current()/SSN/text())) = 9 AND not(string(number(current()/SSN/text())) = 'NaN'))' is an invalid XPath expression. 'boolean((string-length(current()/SSN/text())) = 9 AND not(string(number(current()/SSN/text())) = 'NaN'))' has an invalid token.

However this works fine.

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(current()/SSN/text()) = 9">
    <xsl:if  test="string(number(current()/SSN/text())) != 'NaN'">
        <IdCodeQualifier>
            <xsl:value-of select="'34'" />
        </IdCodeQualifier>
        <SSN>
            <xsl:value-of select="current()/SSN/text()" />                  
        </SSN>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:when>
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `and` instead of `AND`. XPath is case-sensitive.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Kiril says, `AND` is not valid XPath.

Your expressions are also much more verbose than they need to be. You should be able to get by with this:

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(SSN) = 9 and number(SSN) = number(SSN)">
    <IdCodeQualifier>
        <xsl:value-of select="'34'" />
    </IdCodeQualifier>
    <SSN>
        <xsl:value-of select="SSN" />                  
    </SSN>
</xsl:when>
```

In general, I would suggest limiting your use of `text()` unless you have a specific need to use it.